# Return Week zero data

Tags: php, mysql

The following code is designed to pull records for a table for a specific week of the year and summarize the data.  The code runs fine for every week I have tested except week 0 (Sunday Dec 31 of 2017 is the beginning of the week).  If I run the query in phpmyadmin, it does give the desired results.  Can anyone help me to understand what I am doing wrong.

```
try {
            $usid=$_SESSION['uid'];
            $wk = $_GET['wk'];
            $tdy= date("Y-m-d");
            $stmt6 = $db->prepare("
    SELECT 
  YEAR(transaction_date) AS YR,
  COUNT(
    bo_hourly_charges.billing_id_num
  ) AS EVENTS,
  SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN checkout < '16:31:00' 
      THEN 1 
      ELSE 0 
    END
  ) AS early,
  SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN checkout > '16:30:00' 
      THEN 1 
      ELSE 0 
    END
  ) AS late,
  bo_school_enrollment.last_first,
  WEEK(
    bo_hourly_charges.transaction_date
  ) AS wk,
  bo_school_enrollment.student_id,
  bo_school_enrollment.family_id,
  bo_billing_rates.account,
  bo_billing_rates.description,
  bo_school_enrollment.faculty_discount 
FROM
  bo_hourly_charges,
  bo_school_enrollment,
  bo_billing_rates 
WHERE bo_hourly_charges.billing_id_num = bo_school_enrollment.billing_id_num 
  AND billed_by = 'AfterCare' 
  AND bo_hourly_charges.billing_rate_id = bo_billing_rates.billing_rate_id 
  AND WEEK(
    bo_hourly_charges.transaction_date
  ) = :wk 
GROUP BY bo_school_enrollment.faculty_discount,
  bo_school_enrollment.last_first WITH ROLLUP 
           ");
            $stmt6->bindParam(':wk',$wk,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt6->execute();
             // set the resulting array to associative
            $result6 = $stmt6->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
            $count6 = $stmt6->rowCount();
```

Comment: Why do you call it week 0? As far as I know everyone else calls it week 1

Comment: I am running a query prior to this that determines it is week zero and returns it as that  The previous query is "SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(transaction_date) AS YR, WEEK(bo_hourly_charges.transaction_date) as wk FROM bo_hourly_charges WHERE billed_by='AfterCare' ORDER BY transaction_date DESC".  It returns transactions date Jan 3, 2018 as week zero

Answer (score 0):

I found an article that answered my question.  the WEEK function has multiple modes and I need to change the mode to get the desired results. https://www.electricmonk.nl/log/2009/04/13/mysql-week-function-weirdness/